# Removing space byte in nasm x64

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have been trying to encrypt the contents of a file using xor encryption techniquie. My logic for the program is to read the content in the file, xor it with the key, store it to buffer and then print it. I have given an buffer size 200 but buffer size can be any value. When I print the encrypted message I am getting space characters with it.

I tried adding a loop to figure out the string length of the encrypted message where I could only read till the space byte and then print it. But that didnt work out.

Code for my xor encryption :

```
  BITS 64

  %define BUF_SIZE 200
  %define ELEM_SIZE 1

  section .bss
buffer : resb BUF_SIZE
fh: resq 1
filename: resq 1

section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov rax, QWORD [rsp]            ; argument count check
    cmp rax, 0x3
    jne .nofilename

    mov rax, QWORD [rsp + 16]       ; retrieve address of filename from stack
    mov [filename], rax

    mov r13, QWORD[rsp +24]         ;store the key in r13

    xor rax, rax                    ;naddded
    mov rax, SYS_OPEN               ; open file in read only mode
    mov rdi, [filename]
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov rdx, O_RDONLY
    syscall
    cmp rax, 0                      ; test if read failed
    jl .openfailed
    mov [fh], rax

    ;mov rdi,buffer
    ;call .strlen
    ;mov r14, rax

    xor rax, rax                    ;nadded
    mov rax, SYS_READ               ; read BUF_SIZE bytes from file into buffer
    mov rdi, [fh]
    mov rsi, buffer
    mov rdx, BUF_SIZE
    syscall

    mov rdi, buffer                 ;move the buffer to rdi
    call .strlen
    mov r10, rax                    

    mov rdi, r13
    call .strlen
    mov r11, rax
    mov r12,r11

    mov rcx, r10
    ;mov rdx, buffer
    xor rax, rax
    ;mov rbx, r13

    mov r15,0

    .keyloop:

        mov bl, BYTE[r13+r15]

            xor BYTE[buffer+rax],bl
            inc rax
            dec rcx
            cmp rcx,0
            je  .label1

        inc r15
        dec r11
        cmp r11,0
        jne .keyloop
        je  .setloop

    .setloop:
        mov r11,r12
        xor r15, r15
        cmp rcx, 0
        je .label1
        jne .keyloop

    .label1:   
        xor rax, rax
        mov rax, SYS_WRITE              ; write buffer to stdout
        mov rdi, STDOUT
        mov rsi, buffer
        mov rdx, BUF_SIZE
        syscall

    mov rax, SYS_CLOSE              ; close file
    mov rdi, [fh]
    syscall

    xor rdi, rdi                    ; exit(0)
    jmp .final

    .openfailed:                    ; display file open failed error message
        mov rax, SYS_WRITE
        mov rdi, STDERR
        mov rsi, open_error
        mov rdx, open_error_len
        syscall
        mov rdi, 1
        jmp .final

    .nofilename:                    ; display usage message
        mov rax, SYS_WRITE
        mov rdi, STDERR
        mov rsi, usage
        mov rdx, usage_len
        syscall
        mov rdi, 1                  ; exit(1)
        jmp .final

    .final:                        ; exit syscall

        xor r15, r15
        xor r10, r10
        xor r11,r11
        xor rax, rax

        mov rax, SYS_EXIT
        syscall

    .strlen:
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp

        xor rax, rax

        .cmploop:
            cmp BYTE[rdi + rax], 0     ; check if current byte is null
            je .cmpdone                 ; if yes, done
            inc rax                     ; else increment length counter
            jmp .cmploop                ; and continue

        .cmpdone:
            leave
            ret
```

Is there any way that I could get rid of the spaces.

Comment: provide an example, but at the moment if you will put into input file `'AA'` and key `'A'`, then resulting encrypted message will be `"\0\0"`, which you will be probably unable to "print". So it's not clear, what you want. It's just clear you didn't think about it thoroughly.

Comment: "space", a.k.a. ASCII 32 (and for that matter tabs or other whitespace characters) are valid values that may result from `A xor B` for certain values of `A` and `B`. Removing them just because you don't want to see them will destroy the reversibility of your encryption. Of course, as already mentioned, once you encrypt a buffer, you should no longer assume that it's a printable entity, but treat it as simply a sequence of bytes about which you can make very few assumptions...

Comment: @Ped7g : I wanted to print all the encrypted characters in the file with any buffer size given. One method to do is to read byte by byte but since I read  the string in one buffer rather than byte by byte, my output contains unwanted characters of space that got encrypted. I want to know if there is any way to remove those space characters in the above program.

Comment: I don't understand you, put example data into question, what is your "space". Oh.. but you write always buffer_size? When input was shorter, you must write less